# Spring mongodb ArrayOperators filter by $in clause

Tags: spring, mongodb, filter, clause

I have to convert this mongodb aggregate to spring aggregate code

```
{ $addFields: {
    "versions" : { $filter: {
        input: "$versions",
        as: "version",
        cond: {$in: ["$$version.parentId", "$libraries._id"]}
    }}
}}
```

My current code is

```
AddFieldsOperation.with("versions", 
    ArrayOperators.arrayOf("versions").filter().as("version").by(
        ArrayOperators.In.arrayOf("version.parentId").containsValue(
            ArrayOperators.arrayOf("libraries._id")
        )
    )
)
```

but this throws this error:

> $in requires an array as a second argument, found: objectId'

I assume it's because it's not accepting the argument

```
ArrayOperators.arrayOf("libraries._id")
```

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the Spring documentation for [ArrayOperators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ArrayOperators.html), we find the following method definition:

```
arrayOf

public static ArrayOperators.ArrayOperatorFactory arrayOf(String fieldReference)

Take the array referenced by given fieldReference.

Parameters:
    fieldReference - must not be null.
Returns:
```

Notice that it states that `fieldReference` should reference an "array". It seems likely that you want to change `ArrayOperators.arrayOf("libraries._id")` to `ArrayOperators.arrayOf("libraries")` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work, there is no fieldReference configured and I can't change that. The snippet ```{$in: ["$$version.parentId", "$libraries._id"]}``` works in mongo, but it's not correctly converted to spring

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no fieldReference configured"? I'm not familiar with Spring, but wouldn't `fieldReference` simply be a string that matches some array field on your document? Have you attempted the above?

Comment: I thought you meant $ref, which I don't have. I have a fieldReference like you said, but the snippet doesn't work. I want to filter the versions array by checking if versions.parentId is in libraries._id

Answer (score 1):

I had query like

```
{
   coupons: {
      $filter: {
         input: "$coupons",
         as: "coupon",
         cond: { 
             $in: [ "$$coupon._id", ["ABC", "DEF"] ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Below solution worked for me

```
filter("$coupons").as("coupon").by(ArrayOperators.In.arrayOf(couponIds).containsValue("$$coupon._id"))
```

Note: couponIds is List with values ["ABC", "DEF"]

Comment: arrayOf() does not take a list.

Comment: Yes, it does `arrayOf(Collection<?> values)`